# jQuery dialog box performance

Tags: jquery-ui

I am using Jquery dialog box for Confirmation and alert purposes...

This is my code...

```
$( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
            resizable: false,                
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Yes": function() {

                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        });
```

I am not getting any error. So far it's working fine, but it seems the performance is a bit slow. My question is if any performance issue will come in the future? If any performance issue does occur, how would I avoid that?
Please help me with this and correct me if I am wrong in anything.

Answer (score 1):

It is very unlikely that this snippet is slow now or in the future - have you tried timing it?  It is possible that you have some other code in the page that is being triggered by this call but we'd need to see the whole page to be able to investigate this.

Firebug has a decent [JavaScript profiler](http://getfirebug.com/javascript) to help you find performance issues.